# Tickets for integration tests in Pivotal Tracker - chore or feature?

Tags: process, project-management, issue-tracking, pivotaltracker

Say you're using Pivotal Tracker and making tickets for integration tests that are missing in a project. Would you make them as Chores or Features? Curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just kind of learning this myself but the way I understand it is that you would mark this as a chore.

The reasoning is that the end user won't notice this directly.  Sure it'll provide 
them with better quality in the end, but they can't actually "see" it.

Comment: I think that's correct. If it doesn't add business value, then it's a chore. If I don't make any points because the application is missing a lot of tests, zero points is a correct status indicator.